# Is it possible to block third party cookies but allow them when they are first party?

Tags: cookies, firefox

I have been using Cookie Monster in Firefox for a while now to great satisfaction. However, I haven't found a way to allow cookies like Google's on Google's services but block them when I visit other sites that integrate with Google (or Facebook etc.)

Comment: This is probably a question for superuser.

Comment: Any problems with unchecking the obvious "Accept third party cookies" option in FF?

Comment: That requires the "Accept cookies" option to be enabled which defaults Cooke Monster to accept cookies on all sites.

Comment: This question would be a great question if it weren't tied to Cookie Monster.  However, the question about how to block third-party cookies while using Cookie Monster is somehow much less interesting, and better directed to the developers of Cookie Monster to ask them why they broke Firefox's existing option to block third-party cookies.  Therefore, I propose that we edit the question to the form that is actually of interest, namely, how to block third-party cookies in general (not focused on Cookie Monster).  Any opinions on this proposal?

Answer (score 2):

Safari blocks third-party cookies by default.  If you want to check your settings, click the gear icon and go to Preferences >> Security; under "Accept cookies", it should say "Only from sites I visit".  Click OK.

Firefox (without Cookie Monster) blocks third-party cookies if you untick the checkbox saying "Accept third party cookies".  You can get there from Options >> Options >> Privacy.

The [RequestPolicy](https://www.requestpolicy.com/) extension for Firefox can be configured to block those third-party requests (including cookies, but also the requests themselves).

Internet Explorer allows you to block third-party cookies.  Go to Tools >> Internet Options >> Privacy >> Advanced.  Tick the box labelled "Override automatic cookie handling".  Next to "Third-party cookies", select "Block".  Then click OK.

Opera allows you to block third-party cookies.  Go to Tools >> Preferences >> Advanced, select "Cookies" on the left, then select "Accept only cookies from the site I visit".  Click OK.

Chrome allows you to block third-party cookies.  Go to the wrench icon >> Options >> Under the Bonnet >> Content Settings >> Cookies, and tick the box labelled "Block all third-party cookies without exception".  Click OK.

Comment: Safari only blocks some third-party cookies, AFAIK they have a white-list of some allowed third-party cookies. Nowadays, they have a new approach for dealing with cookies called ITP.